# With Angular, how do you force the display of a page whatever the page choosen?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In Angular 9, I'd like to force the display of a page as long as a back end criteria is satisfied (for example until some mandatory informations are filled). That way, the user won't be able to visit any other page of the website.
Do you have any idea how it could be done ?

Thanks

Comment: Try searching `route guards in angular`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve what you want using a [canActivate Gaurd](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

From this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) about `Angular guards`:

> Angular’s route guards are interfaces which can tell the router
> whether or not it should allow navigation to a requested route. They
> make this decision by looking for a true or false return value from a
> class which implements the given guard interface.
> There are five different types of guards and each of them is called in
> a particular sequence. The router’s behavior is modified differently
> depending on which guard is used. The guards are:
>
> 1. CanActivate
> 2. CanActivateChild
> 3. CanDeactivate
> 4. CanLoad
> 5. Resolve